# CSS - Are there font-size standards?

Tags: css, fonts, font-size

I was wondering if there are pre-defined/standardized font-sizes that even though not being a must it is still a good idea to follow when designing a website. I am aware that this might also highly depend on the font that a particular website is using, but let's assume that all fonts are equal and take a popular font like Arial or Helvetica as our base font. For example, what px size would you put for the following font-sizes:

```
--fs-xx-small =
--fs-x-small = 
--fs-small = 
--fs-medium = 16px (1rem)
--fs-large = 
--fs-x-large = 
--fs-xx-large =
```

In addition I assume that for math's sake we can take the default font-size and just use a `rem` unit based on that default size. However, in that case are there any pre-defined/standardized `rem` values?

Last but not least, I managed to get the default font-size value on Chrome by creating a div and then inspecting it via the DevTools panel in the "Computed" section, which revealed that the default unit value is 16px. Therefore, I have set the `fs-medium` to be 16px, but feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Thank you in advance and I really look forward to hear what you think on this topic, as well as what is your solution to using different font-sizes.

Comment: A couple of recommended materials on this topic. 1) [An article about Rems and base font-size](https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/respecting-font-size-preferences-rems-62-5-percent/), 2) [Type-Scale](https://type-scale.com/) that helps you create pre-defined rem values.